# Can access the images in index page and cannot do it in next page why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image

I have put the images in the assets folder but i cannot able to access the image. why and what should i do? And i try accessing from the views as `<img src="/assets/logo.png">`

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/assets/logo.png")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use image_tag:

```
<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets